# Why does the UITableVIew scroll down but not up when keyboard is shown?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uikeyboard

I have `textViews` in a `tableView`. When `textViews` (towards the bottom of the `tableView`) get selected the keyboard pops up, and hides the `textView`, and you can't scroll down either. So I added the following code:

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    myTableView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    myTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {
        [self.myTabelView scrollRectToVisible:activeField.frame animated:YES];
    }
}
```

I now have the opposite problem. When the keyboard does show, towrad the top doesn't show, and it's not possible to scroll all the way up either.

Comment: since you already set the insets, you don't need to set frame any more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi and did you try to use TPKeyboardAvoiding ? I use it to solve such cases without to need to code anything... You can try it as CocoaPod quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm not using an xib file. Everything is in the storyboard, and TPKeyboardAvoiding requires an xib file... I think

Comment: In storyboard you can also assign custom class for view, there is no difference, you can use it in storyboard also, this library is really cool i use it in each app...